# How can we calculate the "degree" of conjugation?

Tags: organic-chemistry, resonance

So a conjugated system is a system of connected p orbitals or alternating single and multiple bonds.

I know that conventionally, we count the number of adjacent parallel p orbitals or alternating single-double bonds to see which molecule is "more conjugated" or not. However, when considering the following molecules:
[image]
I cannot seem to find out which molecule is "more" conjugated or not.

Is there a way to calculate the degree of conjugation? And in this case, would the rhodamine B be the most conjugated compound in the list?

Comment: For a deeper insight on the degree of conjugation, have a look at Clar's rule, for instance: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3982536/

Comment: Not a "degree" but you can calculate *energy* of conjugation,

Comment: There are several but this is a field itself. Note that in complex structure   counting how many double bonds are in alternate sequences does not suffice. The first example that comes to my mind is that of antiaromatic cycles.